# Storage drive formatting, permissions and setup?

Tags: disk-management

```
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                         LABEL   

sda    vfat       1,8T                                    Ostava   
sdb             238,5G                                    
├─sdb1 vfat       512M /boot/efi                          
└─sdb2 ext4       238G /                                  
sdc              29,8G                                    
└─sdc1 vfat      29,8G /media/m/8765-4321
```

I am not getting around Ubuntu file manager well, very used to Windows system with My Computer --> drives.

Recently I decided to try and figure out my storage drive, since SSD is getting full. 
It seemed inaccessible, I've activated it by formatting it. Wasn't sure which file system would work as universal (for my camera and Win compatibility etc), so I used FAT. Should I have used NTFS instead?

Ostava - 2TB drive is now locked. Somehow I could copy files at first, but not anymore. That's the priority issue I'm trying to solve at this point.

> 1) Are you dual-booting with Windows now?

No, but I might in future.

> 2) NTFS is, indeed, a better choice if you need to share files between
>   Windows and Ubuntu.

Thanks, I will work toward it when making partitions.

> 3) I don't see a partition (e.g., /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, ...) on your
>   2TB drive. Did you make one?

I didn't make any partitions I wanted, cause GNOME Disks I used I couldn't figure out how.

> 4) [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119490464) is a reasonable starting point.

Thanks, I'll check it out!

I'm using File Manager and Double Commander for Ostava. Both let me read from but not write on it.

[Disks sda screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttzV4.png)

I've installed Gparted, but it won't launch. It asks for my pw, then nothing happens when I enter it.

I think sda/Ostava just needs permissions changed, otherwise it's fine. It is internal HDD, original laptop part and it was never physically unplugged.

In Terminal I'm logged as root user. Somehow I've done it awhile ago while trying to fix something else. I don't know how to manage/switch users within system and/or change permissions.

Comment: The 'loops' are compressed Snaps, which is how Ubuntu installs a lot of apps you choose from the Ubuntu Software Center. This method makes apps less likely to interfere with each other and more likely to install without dependency problems, although it does take more space (as you noted), What are you doing with that 'Ostava' vfat 2TB drive? What's in there? Please click [edit] and give us a little more information to help us help you. Please do not use Add Comment; use [edit].

Comment: Can you restate this as a question?

Comment: @MeanNah 1) Are you dual-booting with Windows now? 2) NTFS is, indeed, a better choice if you need to share files between Windows and Ubuntu. 3) I don't see a partition (e.g., /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, ...)  on your 2TB drive. Did you make one?  4) https://www.amazon.com/Linux-All-One-Dummies-Computer/dp/1119490464/ is a reasonable starting point. .Please click [edit] and explain how you are accessing and using the 2TB drive, and omit last sentence, to keep the scope limited and reasonable in this question.

Comment: Can you open the app `Disks` and select the `sda` and then take a screenshot of the Disk app? Upload the picture in imagur.com and add the link into your question. You should also install Gparted in Ubuntu using the **Ubuntu Software** Center. Gparted is very useful for working with partitions.

Comment: Since the drive is now read-only it is possible that it was disconnected without being properly unmounted/ejected/"safely removed".